# getting data out of hive and into mysql @ AWS?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I'd love to use Sqoop but don't think it is worth running the Cloudera stack @ AWS over ElasticMapReduce (which I really like) just for this.

My current thought is just to write the data I need moved to an external table housed @ S3 and then write a script to import it into mysql.  Amazon has some stuff with SimpleDB ([example](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/2854)), but I am not sure about that route either?  Fine with the data living at S3, just wondering if anyone has a better idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution which I use and works great:

1. Just as you suggested put your data into S3 bucket. You can create a table that is hosted on S3 and has a e.g. tab-separated format. If you use one reducer in your final step you will end up with one file only.
2. Download the data to your MySQL server, my favourite tool would be [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)
3. Import your data straight into MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE...